# capture error from catchError - http.post

Tags: javascript, angular, http, rxjs, try-catch

component which is calling submitUser

```
this.someservice.submitUser(postData).subscribe((data) => {
      this.viewUsers();
    }, (err) => {
      console.log('error in the component', err);
    });
```

Here is the service file with submitUser function

```
 public submitUser(reqBody ) {
    return this.httpService.post('roles', reqBody, '/business/create')
    .pipe(
      catchError(
        this.httpService.handleError())
    );
  }
```

and here is the httpService Post and handleError methods

```
 public post<JSON>(url: string, body: any, param?: string, options?: IRequestOptions): Observable<JSON> {

    return this.intercept(this.http.post<JSON>(this.getURLFromMethodName(url, param), body, this.requestOptions(options)));
  }
```

```
handleError<T> (operation = 'operation', result?: T) {
      return (error: any): Observable<T> => {

        // TODO: send the error to remote logging infrastructure
        console.error('error from httpclient', error); // log to console instead

        throw throwError(new Error(error));
      };
    }
```

handleError adisplays the console error, I am trying to return/capture this error in my submitUser function in service.ts

How do i do that ? Any Inputs appreciated, Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `handleError()` method returns an `error observable` along with logging the error to the console.

When some error occurs, the `catchError` operator takes that error and gives it to `handleError()` which in turn returns an error observable.

**CASE 1: Returning the error**

If you need to pass this error on to the subscriber, you don't have to do anything. The `catchError` operator is already taking care of it for you.

With the same code, let's say some component is consuming your service, then you can just write

```
someService.submitUser().subscribe((res) => {
   \\ handle success
}, (err) => {
   console.error(err); // Will print the error
});
```

Whenever the error occurs, the catchError is going to return the error observable back to its subscriber and it will go in the error function of the observer as shown in the code snippet above.

**CASE 2: Handling the error**

The `catchError` operator accepts a function that takes `error` as an argument. If you return another observable inside this instead of throwing an error, the subscriber won't get to know that the error had occurred, the success function of the observer will execute.

```
// Inside the service

public submitUser(reqBody ) {
  return this.httpService.post('roles', reqBody, '/business/create')
  .pipe(
    catchError((err) => of([1,2,3]));
}


 // Inside the component consuming the service

someService.submitUser().subscribe((res) => {
   console.log(res) // Will print [1,2,3]
}, (err) => {
   \\ handle error
});
```

Comment: ```this.manageAccessService.submitUser(postData).subscribe((data) => {
      this.viewUsers();
    }, (err) => {
      console.log('error in the component', err);
    });``` I did this in my component but how do i capture the error from handleError method

Comment: Your `handleError` function returns a function that throws the error observable, the `catchError` gets this function and throws the same error to the subscriber. This means, the `err` variable in the component subscribe method should have the error thrown by the `handleError` function.

Comment: the err in component returns an observable Observable {_isScalar: false, _subscribe: ƒ} how to i resolve it

Comment: In the handleError function, instead of `throw throwError(new Error(error));`, use `return throwError(new Error(error));`

Comment: err in the component prints  Error: [object Object] Is there something that we need to pass through catchError ?

Comment: That means the error that you received is an object. The actual string error message must be a property inside that object.

Comment: Try doing a plain `console.log(err);` inside the component subscribe error block, it'll directly print the error object in the console.

Comment: but it is not printing the object, im not sure what i am missing, it gives Error: [object Object]

Comment: I fixed it, I had to put return throwError(error); instead of return throwError(new Error(error)); in my handleError. ThankYou